# How to select best features in Dataframe using the Information Gain measure in scikit-learn

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I want to identify the 10 best features of a Dataframe using the Information Gain measure (Mutual Info in scikit-learn) and display them in a table (in ascending order according to the score obtained by the Information Gain).

In this example, `features` is the Dataframe that contains all the interesting training data that could tell if a restaurant will close or not.

```py
# Initialization of data and labels
x = features.copy () # "x" contains all training data
y = x ["closed"] # "y" contains the labels of the records in "x"

# Elimination of the class column (closed) of features
x = x.drop ('closed', axis = 1)

# this is x.columns, sorry for the mix french and english
features_columns = ['moyenne_etoiles', 'ville', 'zone', 'nb_restaurants_zone',
       'zone_categories_intersection', 'ville_categories_intersection',
       'nb_restaurant_meme_annee', 'ecart_type_etoiles', 'tendance_etoiles',
       'nb_avis', 'nb_avis_favorables', 'nb_avis_defavorables',
       'ratio_avis_favorables', 'ratio_avis_defavorables',
       'nb_avis_favorables_mention', 'nb_avis_defavorables_mention',
       'nb_avis_favorables_elites', 'nb_avis_defavorables_elites',
       'nb_conseils', 'nb_conseils_compliment', 'nb_conseils_elites',
       'nb_checkin', 'moyenne_checkin', 'annual_std', 'chaine',
       'nb_heures_ouverture_semaine', 'ouvert_samedi', 'ouvert_dimanche',
       'ouvert_lundi', 'ouvert_vendredi', 'emporter', 'livraison',
       'bon_pour_groupes', 'bon_pour_enfants', 'reservation', 'prix',
       'terrasse']

# normalization
std_scale = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(features[features_columns])
normalized_data = std_scale.transform(features[features_columns])
labels = np.array(features['closed'])

# split the data 
train_features, test_features, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(normalized_data, labels, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42)

labels_true = ?
labels_pred = ?

# I dont really know how to use this function to achieve what i want
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification



# Get the mutual information coefficients and convert them to a data frame
coeff_df =pd.DataFrame(features,
                         columns=['Coefficient'], index=x.columns)

coeff_df.head()
```

What is the correct syntax using Mutual Info score to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong with your attempt(s)? The [sklearn user guide on clusterin](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#mutual-info-score) has examples of syntax and use

Comment: does labels_true and labels_pred in the examle are my train_features and test_features in my case?

Comment: it's just confusing when they show 0101 in those examples

Comment: labels_true and labels_pred are the actual y values, and the y values predicted by the model. So in your case, `labels_true` would be `test_labels`, and `labels_pred` would be the labels returned by calling `model.predict(test_features)` (assuming you've fitted a model to your input features and labels first, of course)

Comment: @G.Anderson oh so i need to train a model before? like decision tree Classifier or random forest? I thought that part came after. In my head it's more like : I select the 10 best features of a Dataframe using the Information Gain measure and then i use those features to train a model. So i'm confused

Comment: Yes, that's what you must do. Think of it this way: How can you select important features if you haven't trained a model on those features? How would you know which is important? A feature can only be important _to a model_, and importance is how much that feature affects the predictive power of a model

Comment: @G.Anderson Oh i see so i will need to train the first time to Identify which features are the best and then train a second time using those features only?

Comment: @G.Anderson Also, adjusted_mutual_info_score is giving me a single score, how can i identify what columns are the best with this only value?

Comment: I disagree. There is no need to train the model for feature selection (FS).  Rather, FS methods exist because they help to determine relevant features which can then be passed into a learning algorithm to build a model. See these posts [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64825/should-feature-selection-be-performed-only-on-training-data-or-all-data), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2306/feature-selection-for-final-model-when-performing-cross-validation-in-machine)

Comment: @mnm alright, but what is the syntax to do what i've said initially in my post o.0

Comment: @mnm that's a fair point in general, but in the case of this particular metric, sklearn's mutualinfoscore, there has to be a trained model to get predictions against which to score

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The adjusted_[mutual_info_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.adjusted_mutual_info_score.html) compares ground truth labels with labels predictions from a classifier. Both label arrays must have the same shape (nsamples,).

You need Scikit-Learn's [mutual_info_classif](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif.html) for what you are trying to achieve. Pass the array of features and the corresponding labels to mutual_info_classif to get back the estimated mutual information between each feature and the target.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

# Generate a sample data frame
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=4,
                           n_informative=2, n_redundant=2,
                           random_state=0, shuffle=False)
feature_columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
features = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=feature_columns)

# Get the mutual information coefficients and convert them to a data frame
coeff_df =pd.DataFrame(mutual_info_classif(X, y).reshape(-1, 1),
                         columns=['Coefficient'], index=feature_columns)
```

Output

```
features.head(3)
Out[43]: 
          A         B         C         D
0 -1.668532 -1.299013  0.799353 -1.559985
1 -2.972883 -1.088783  1.953804 -1.891656
2 -0.596141 -1.370070 -0.105818 -1.213570

# Displaying only the top two features. Adjust the number as required.
coeff_df.sort_values(by='Coefficient', ascending=False)[:2]

Out[44]: 
   Coefficient
B     0.523911
D     0.366884
```

Comment: So what does make_classification do in here? what does n_informative, random_state do? and what is X,y? If i understand correctly, X is all training data and y is  the labels of the records in "X"? And how can I  display the 10 best features in a table in ascending order according to the score obtained by the Information Gain?

Comment: it tells me int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DataFrame'

Comment: do i have to use make_classification ?

Comment: Of course not, this is just for the example. I am reworking the answer, hopefully it will become more clear.

Comment: my problem is that i dont know what is in your X and y. I already have a dataframe features, where do i have to put it to have coeff_df? I cant use mutual_info_classif(X, y) because i dont have (X, y) given by your make_classification.

Comment: I updated my post to show you what ive tried, i get a bunch of NaNs  for coeff_df

Comment: I thought it would be obvious: mutual_info_classif(x, labels).

Comment: alright thanks, and last thing, does .reshape(-1, 1) is necessary for me? not sure what it does

Comment: Yes, it is. It reshapes the array from a wide to a long format, e.g. row to a column.